# Nested Loop for printing out different strings (Python)

Tags: python, list, loops, nested-loops

I would like to print the right strings from a list I have, while looping through another list I have.

My two lists look like this:

```
overview_list = ['1','2','3']
my_list = ['name1', 'year1', 'date1', 'numbre1', 
'name2', 'year2', 'date2', 'numbre2',
'name3','year3','date3', 'numbre3']
```

I would like to loop through the `overview_list` and for every string I would like to print() the corresponding strings from `my_list`.

These are:

for '1' from `overview_list` it sould be printed: 'name1', 'year1', 'date1', 'numbre1'

for  '2' from `overview_list` it should be printed: 'name2', 'year2', 'date2', 'numbre2'

and so on....

I think this could be done with a nested loop, but I am still a beginner in Python and do not know how.
Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to print every string in a different row:

```
overview_list = ['1','2','3']
my_list = ['name1', 'year1', 'date1', 'numbre1', 
'name2', 'year2', 'date2', 'numbre2',
'name3','year3','date3', 'numbre3']

for number in overview_list:
    for elem in my_list:
        if number in elem:
            print(elem)
```

Another option if you would like to print together all the strings that relate to one number:

```
overview_list = ['1','2','3']
my_list = ['name1', 'year1', 'date1', 'numbre1', 
'name2', 'year2', 'date2', 'numbre2',
'name3','year3','date3', 'numbre3']

for number in overview_list:
    for elem in my_list:
        if number in elem:
            print(elem, end=" ")
    print()
```

BTW you wrote numbre instead of number in 'my_list'

**An addition after your comment:**
In order to use the ordinal number of any string in overview_list - try this:

```
overview_list = ['x','y','z']
my_list = ['name1', 'year1', 'date1', 'numbre1', 
'name2', 'year2', 'date2', 'numbre2',
'name3','year3','date3', 'numbre3']

for index, item in enumerate(overview_list, 1):
    for elem in my_list:
        if str(index) in elem:
            print(elem, end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: That works with `overview_list = [1,2,3]`, but what could I do if  `overview_list = [x,y,z]`, but everything else remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

try this, you don't need nested loop's instead using `range(start, stop, step)` + `splicing`

```
over_view = 3

for i in range(0, len(my_list), over_view + 1):
    print(", ".join(my_list[i: i + over_view + 1]))
```

---

```
name1, year1, date1, numbre1
name2, year2, date2, numbre2
name3, year3, date3, numbre3
```

Comment: I am trying to generalise this therefore I choose `overview_list = [1,2,3]`, but it could also be `overview_list = [x,y,z]`

Comment: @Etiende What are the values of ``[x,y,z]`` & how is your existing output going to change based on those values ?

Comment: x,y,z are just names as a string. For every name in `overview_list` the corresponding strings from `my_list`, which are name1, year1, date1, number1, for the first string on `overview_list` (here [x]). The corresponding strings from `my_list` for the secound string from `overview_list` (here [y]) would be name2, year2, date2, number2 and so on

Comment: @Etiende, So are you looking for some nested list to be created from my_list, ```[[name1,year1..], [name2, year2..]..]```